# Determine MapKit tiles for visibleMapRect

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkmaprect

I saw simple code for calculating a grid of tile bounds needed for a given `MKMapRect` but I can't find it now. IIRC it was a function built-in to `MapKit`.

Given a `MKMapRect` like `mapview.visibleMapRect` and zoom level, how can I calculate an array of tile paths that will be used for the given rect?

```
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapview.delegate = self

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.0, longitude: -120.0)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.0, 1.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let rect = mapview.visibleMapRect
    
        let requiredTiles = ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with MapKit and MKTileOverlays for years, and I don't recall ever seeing a built-in way to calculate tiles in an area. But there are some libraries out there that can help with it. For example, [gis-tools](https://github.com/Outdooractive/gis-tools/tree/main), and the `MapTile` struct.

You can initialize a `MapTile` with a coordinate and zoom level, so you can calculate the northwest and southeast corners of your `MKMapRect`, convert them to coordinates and then to `MapTiles`, and then use a simple nested `for` loop to go through the tile keys.

That would look something like this:

```swift
let nwCoord = Coordinate3D(mapRect.origin.coordinate)
let seCoord = Coordinate3D(MKMapPoint(x: mapRect.maxX, y: mapRect.maxY).coordinate)
let nwTile = MapTile(coordinate: nwCoord, atZoom: zoom)
let seTile = MapTile(coordinate: seCoord, atZoom: zoom)

var result = Set<MapTile>()
for x in nwTile.x...seTile.x {
    for y in nwTile.y...seTile.y {
        result.insert(MapTile(x: x, y: y, z: zoom))
    }
}
```

Maybe not the exact elegant solution you were looking for, but hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing I must have seen someone's extension that did it but thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer for most use cases is that you don't do the calculation, and let MapKit do the work:

You define your own subclass of MKTileOverlay, set

```
class DigitransitTileOverlay: MKTileOverlay {
    
    override func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "cdn.digitransit.fi"
        // standard tile size for MKTileOverlay is 265
        //let startPath = "/map/v1/hsl-map-256" // the hsl-map part can be customized with language parameters
        // standard tile size for digitransit is 512
        let startPath = "/map/v1/hsl-map" // the hsl-map part can be customized with language parameters
        let size: String = ""  // @2x for retina, empty for normal
        urlComponents.path = startPath + "/\(path.z)/\(path.x)/\(path.y)\(size).png"
        
        let url: URL = urlComponents.url!

        return url
    }
}
```

Then you set

```
digiTransitTileOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = false
digiTransitTileOverlay.tileSize = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
mapView.addOverlay(digiTransitTileOverlay, level: .aboveRoads)
```

tileSize is not necessary, but appears to make some servers faster, as popular web libraries prefer 512 x 512 so this tile size is cached my many servers.

and define a renderer:

```
public override func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer? {
    if let tileOverlay = overlay as? DigitransitTileOverlay {
        let tileOverlayRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: tileOverlay)
        return tileOverlayRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

As you see, url(forTilePath is called by MapKit for each necessary tile in the region you have set. You get parameters for each tile in MKTileOverlayPath

Comment: I do appreciate your help, but I’m already doing that. Before requesting tiles, I’m using `MKMapSnapshotter` and want to cut the snapshot into tiles. The problem is that the overlay doesn’t seem to provide the pixels of Apple’s map, which I require for image processing. Perhaps there is a way to access the underlying layer pixels?

Comment: I see, but I don't see that described in the question you asked.

Comment: Indeed as that is a different question. If you're suggesting there is a way, I'd be happy to post a new question.

Comment: Posted a new question. If you could take a look I'd appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284348/access-underlying-base-imagery-with-mktileoverlay-or-mktileoverlayrenderer

Comment: Note that I did not ask how to let MapKit calculate the tiles for me. I specifically asked how to calculate the tile paths.

Comment: You need to calculate a zoom value:         static func zoom(distanceInMeter: Double, lat: CLLocationDegrees, mapViewWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(log2(latitudeCircumference(lat: lat) * Double(mapViewWidth) / (256 * distanceInMeter)))
        }

Comment: Region to Zoom: extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    func zoom(mapViewWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return MapMath.zoom(distanceInMeter: self.longitudinalMeters, lat: self.center.latitude, mapViewWidth: mapViewWidth)
    }
    func zoomInt(mapViewWidth: CGFloat) -> Int {
        let result = Int(self.zoom(mapViewWidth: mapViewWidth))
        if result >= 0 {
            return result
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}

Comment: Then you find (not iOS / Swift sepcific) formulas on the web how to tile with a given zoom.

Comment: I know how to calculate slippy tile bounds. Like I said in the post, I recall seeing an elegant way of calculating a grid of tiles needed for a given `MapKit` view.